# TigerVNC Viewer "The connection was dropped by the server before the session could be established"

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, tigervnc

I want to set up a GUI on an AWS instance, following the instructions in [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-2-install-gui/). I was able to do this on my first instance, but there was insufficient RAM for my purposes so I upgraded to a larger server.

Now when I attempt to connect I get the error ""The connection was dropped by the server before the session could be established. Attempt to reconnect?" I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I've updated everything to the new server's network, I can Putty into it just fine, but I can't get TigerVNC to work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.